# How should I structure a batch processing pipeline using Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm slowly but surely getting the hang of twisted, but I'm not sure how I should be approaching this particular project.

I'm trying to create a class for batch processing of web pages.  There are multiple web pages that I would like to process independently, so it makes sense to have a pipeline of sorts for each url.  Additionally, I would like to call a one-time preprocessing function before any of the urls are processed, and when all urls have been processed, I would like to call a post-processing function.  Importantly, I'd like to be able to subclass this processing class and override certain methods based on the contents I'm trying to process -- not all web-pages will require the same processing steps.

If this were synchronous code, I would probably do this with a context manager.  Consider the following example code:

```
class Pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, urls):
        self.urls = urls  # iterable
        self.continue = False

    def __enter__(self):
        self.continue = self.preprocess()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.continue:  # if we decided to run the batch pipeline...
            self.postprocess()

    def preprocess(self):
        # does some stuff and returns a bool

    def postprocess(self):
        # do some stuff

    def pipeline(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            try:
                # download url, do some stuff
            except:
                # recover so that other urls are not interrupted
```

After which, I would use it as follows:

```
with Pipeline(list_of_urls) as p:
    p.pipeline()
```

This works well with synchronous network operations, but not with Twisted, since the pipeline function will return before the end of the processing pipeline, thus calling `__exit__`.

Additionally, I would like each URL's processing to take place completely separately because there may be conditional branching based on the result of my queries.  For this reason, using Twisted's `DeferredList` is not desirable.

In a nutshell, I need the following:

- Preprocess must run before all else
- Postprocess must run when the following is true:

  - At least one url began processing (preprocess returns `True`)
  - All urls have either completed or thrown an exception

What's the sanest way to set something like this up with Twisted?  The issue I'm having is that some of the code involves asynchronous IO and some is just straight synchronous logic (i.e. processing the results in memory), so I'm not sure how to make the whole thing work with deferreds (or whether I even should).

Any advice?

Comment: "Additionally, I would like each URL's processing to take place completely separately because there may be conditional branching based on the result of my queries. For this reason, using Twisted's DeferredList is not desirable." 

Where is the conditional branching taking place?

Comment: Have you considered just using scrapy?

Comment: @jomido, the conditional branching will always take place during the middle (pipeline) stage.

Jean-PaulCalderone, scrapy is a huge clunking framework and for a variety of reasons I'd rather avoid using it.

Comment: Scrapy might be bigger than what you *desire*; but it is designed for this exact job; scraping http resources, processing the results in a pipeline.

Comment: "... is a huge clunking framework ..." doesn't sound like the kind of reason I'd accept for re-implementing the functionality of an existing tool rather than re-using it.  However, if you're dead set on that, then you can at least look at scrapy and learn from how they implemented their pipeline.  That way, even though you're redoing a lot of the work they did already, you're not forced to relearn all the same lessons they learned - at least not the hard way, not without the benefit of their experience.  (Though just using scrapy is still probably better. ;)

Comment: @blz I'm not certain why using DeferredList isn't desirable, then. Perhaps I'm not fully understanding.

Also, it's unclear to me how "At least one url began processing" and "(preprocess returns True)" are equivalent.  As far as I can tell, preprocess() returning True doesn't indicate at all that one url has begun processing.

Comment: @jomido, I was admittedly unclear.  The idea is that urls begin processing if `preprocess` returns true.  I'm choosing to consider these two as equivalent.  The more I think about it thought, the more it might make sense to handle everything with a `DeferredList`

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone, unfortunately I don't have much of a choice.  I tried going the scrapy route, but it really *is* too massive.  In any case, looking to their pipeline is probably not a bad idea -- I'll start browsing their code straightaway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of the comments for the original question, I would suggest using DeferredList in combination with [maybeDeferred](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.maybeDeferred.html). I propose the latter because of this:

> The issue I'm having is that some of the code involves asynchronous IO and some is just straight synchronous logic (i.e. processing the results in memory), so I'm not sure how to make the whole thing work with deferreds (or whether I even should).

Using a maybeDeferred allows you to treat all of your function calls as though they were asynchronous, whether they actually are or not.

Comment: `maybeDeferred` seems like what I want.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Following structure helps me in close condition:

```
def Processor:
   def __init__()
      self.runned = 0
      self.hasSuccess = True
      self.preprocess()

   def launch(self, urls):
      for url in urls:
        dfrd = url.process()
        dfrd.addCallback(self.succ)
        dfrd.addErrback(self.fail)
        self.runned += 1

   def fail(self, reason):
        self.runned -= 1
        if self.runned == 0 and self.hasSuccess:
            self.postprocess()

   def succ(self, arg):   
        self.runned -= 1
        self.hasSuccess = True
        if not self.runned
            self.postprocess()
```